# A sesquilinear form is left non-degenerate if and only if it is right non-degenerate

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a finite dimensional vector space $V$, how to prove that a sesquilinear form is left non-degenerate if and only if it is right non-degenerate, where a form $f$ is said to be left non-degenerate: if $f(x, y)=0 \forall y \in V$, then $x= 0$.

Thanks

Comment: Can you translate "sesquilinear form" to "matrix"?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes sir.

Comment: Good. And in that translation, what does it mean that a sesquilinear form is left or right non-degenerate?

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\}$ be a basis for $V$ and $A$ the matrix of $f$ relative to $B$. Let us prove that $f$ is *not* left non-degenerate if and only if it is *not* right non-degenerate, this will give us the result.

Suppose $f$ is not left non-degenerate. There exist $\alpha_0 \neq 0$ such that $f(\alpha_0,\beta)=0$ for all $\beta \in V$, and $\alpha_0=\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i\alpha_i$ for some scalars $x_i$, not all equal to zero. If we let $X=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 & \cdots & x_n \end{pmatrix}^T$, this means
$\begin{pmatrix} \bar{z_1} & \cdots & \bar{z_n} \end{pmatrix}AX=0$ for all scalars $z_1,\ldots,z_n$, which implies that $AX=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \cdots & 0\end{pmatrix}^T$ and thus $A$ is non invertible since $X$ is non zero. Therefore there exist $Y=\begin{pmatrix} y_1 & \cdots & y_n \end{pmatrix}^T$, with $y_i$ not all equal to zero, such that $Y^*A=0$, implying that $Y^*A\begin{pmatrix} w_1 & \cdots & w_n \end{pmatrix}^T=0$ for all scalars $w_1,\ldots,w_n$. Let $\beta_0=\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i\alpha_i$, now we have $f(\alpha,\beta_0)=0$ for all $\alpha \in V$ with $\beta_0 \neq 0$, i.e. $f$ is not right non-degenerate.

The other implication is proved similarly and we can conclude.